# Getting notified when a new message is sent to a chat room (when the chat room isn't joined)

Tags: ios, quickblox, chatroom

For group chat, I would like to update the unread badge in my chat list view whenever a new message is sent to a chat room. However, if the room isn't joined, I don't get notified via `chatRoomDidReceiveMessage:fromRoomJID`.

Is there a way to get notified when a new message is sent to a chat room without joining each and every chat room in order to update the unread badge counter in my chat list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.. If push notification is set up, you will get a push when a new message arrives **if** you're not inside a chat room. Note that if you **are** inside a chat room, you will not get this push notification.